# Why are 2 different lengths are showing when using value_counts() and shape[0]?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, shapes

I am trying to find out how many records are there and I thought that there were 2 ways to show the total number of records. However, they show different lengths, why is this happening?

I listed both ways below, to elaborate further one line has the .shape[0] attribute while the other has the .value_counts() attribute

```
df.loc[(df['rental_store_city'] == 'Woodridge') & (df['film_rental_duration'] > 5)].shape[0]

output: 3186

df.loc[(df['rental_store_city'] == 'Woodridge') & (df['film_rental_duration'] > 5)].value_counts()
```

[output image that shows length of 3153](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX0A3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `value_counts` groups by the duplicates and counts the number of them, and it removes the extra duplicates, so that would make the dataframe shorter.

As you can see in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html):

> Return a Series containing counts of unique rows in the DataFrame.

**Example:**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 1, 3]})
>>> df
   a
0  1
1  2
2  1
3  3
>>> df.value_counts()
a
1    2
3    1
2    1
dtype: int64
>>>
```

As you can see the duplicates made the code dataframe shorter.

If you want to get the length of the dataframe don't use `value_counts`, use `len`:

```
len(df.loc[(df['rental_store_city'] == 'Woodridge') & (df['film_rental_duration'] > 5)])
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply.
I was wondering why len() vs shape[0], they give the same result. is len() more efficient?